# Does Hellkite Tyrant in combination with Mycosynth Lattice steal lands?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say you attack someone for player damage with [Hellkite Tyrant](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hellkite%20Tyrant) whilst [Mycosynth Lattice](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mycosynth%20Lattice) is in play (played by you if it makes a difference). Do you get control of all of your opponents lands? The answer to [this question](http://www.mtgsalvation.com/forums/magic-fundamentals/magic-rulings/magic-rulings-archives/267486-land-permanent) says that lands are permanents, and since all permanents are turned in to artifacts does Hellkite Tyrant steal them? I'm asking this because it feels so OP that I'm wondering if there is more to this.

Comment: In regards to the comment that it's OP, it's just one of many combos in Magic. It requires two cards from very distant sets (so it won't come up in Standard), both costing 6, and it also requires that the Hellkite is able to get an attack through. While it is a very impactive combo if it goes off, it's also relatively easy to deal with or stall out.

Comment: I know, I use the combo ;) I've just been wondering if what I was doing was really "legal". Thanks!

Comment: By the way, the phrase "player damage" is rather odd to my ear. I guess you meant damage dealt to a player, but it just seems strange because who or what the damage is dealt to is not a property of the damage itself. (For comparison, we say "deathtouch damage", "infect damage", "lifelink damage", etc. because those are effectively properties of the damage - though if you want to get technical they're properties of the _source_.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, as you stated correctly, lands are permanents:

> 110.1. A permanent is a card or token on the battlefield.
>
> ...
>
> 110.4. There are five permanent types: artifact, creature, enchantment, **land**, and planeswalker.

Enemy Lands are Artifact [Basic] Lands now due to Mycosynth Lattice, and nothing stops you from getting control of them if you deal combat damage with Hellkite Tyrant.